# Can we give the complete list of $n$ such that there exists a group of order $n$ whose automorphism group is nontrivial and of odd order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

I was wondering if it is possible to determine all $n$ such that there exists a group $G$ with odd $|\operatorname{Aut}(G)|>1$. The following numbers are some examples that occur in the list:

- $729=3^6$ (by direct computation);
- $p^5$ for odd primes $p$ (from [Finite groups with odd order automorphism groups](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20490163));
- $3p^5$ and $3p^6$ for primes $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$ (from [Complete groups of order $3p^6$](https://www.advgrouptheory.com/journal/Volumes/2/M.J.%20Curran,%20R.S.%20Dark%20-%20Complete%20groups%20of%20order%203p6.pdf)),

... and so on.

If the concrete list cannot be given, can we say something about the prime factors? For example, given a set of odd primes $\{p_1,\cdots,p_r\}$, does there exists a group $G$ such that the prime factors of $|G|$ are exactly those $p_1,\cdots,p_r$ and that $|\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$ is odd?

Any help/reference appreciated.

**Edit:** Those even orders are twice the odd orders. If $|G|$ is even and $|\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$ is odd, then $G=G_0\times C_2$ with $|G_0|$ odd and $|\operatorname{Aut}(G_0)|$ odd, as stated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/357294/1039170). Thanks Dietrich Burde for providing this link in the comments.

Comment: We can of course list them , one by one. But whether we can classify those $n$ is another story.

Comment: @Peter You're right :) I added the word "complete" to the title.

Comment: There is a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357245/on-order-automorphisms-group-of-a-finite-group) saying when $Aut(G)$ has *even* order, with some references. I don't think that there is a complete list. Your question has been asked more or less already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165784/existence-of-group-g-with-g2-and-automorphism-group-of-odd-order), right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well, I don't quite think so. I had been aware of these questions and the references listed before posting this question, and I was more interested in finding the possible orders, not a particular example.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You're right, my fault. But still, I think there is some hope that some criteria on the possible prime factors of such orders could be given. For example, I would be happy to receive an answer like "a group of order $3^r5^s$ can/cannot have an odd number of automorphisms because $\{3,5\}$ satisfies/does not satisfy a particular criterion".

Comment: Why not  just take a direct product  of examples of order $p^5$ with $p$ ranging over any set of odd primes?

Comment: @DerekHolt You are absolutely correct. How silly I was!